# Search items in container based on criteria and priority

Tags: c++, search, containers

I am trying to find an elegant way to do the following :

Let's say I have for example the following class :

```
class Foo {
    public: 
        SomeType bar;
}
```

`foo.bar` can be equal to any of the following constants : `BAR1`, `BAR2`, `BAR3`, ..., `BARN`

Now I have a container of such elements : `std::vector<Foo> fooVec;` and I want to find the first element for which `foo.bar` is equal to `BAR1`, if there is none, then I want the first element for which `foo.bar` is equal to `BAR2`, and so on.

Here is an example code to test the algorithm :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Foo {
private:
    static int id_counter;
public:
    enum class Bar { _1, _2, _3, _4 };

    Bar bar;
    int id;

    Foo(Foo::Bar bar) : bar(bar), id(id_counter++) {}
};
int Foo::id_counter = 0;

const Foo& findFoo(const std::vector<Foo>& vec) {
    // Find first element verifying foo.bar == 1, or first verifying foo.bar == 2, etc...
}

int main() {
    std::vector<Foo> fooVec1({Foo(Foo::Bar::_2),
                              Foo(Foo::Bar::_4),
                              Foo(Foo::Bar::_1),
                              Foo(Foo::Bar::_3)});

    std::vector<Foo> fooVec2({Foo(Foo::Bar::_3),
                              Foo(Foo::Bar::_2),
                              Foo(Foo::Bar::_4),
                              Foo(Foo::Bar::_2)});

    std::cout << findFoo(fooVec1).id << std::endl; //Expected output: 2
    std::cout << findFoo(fooVec2).id << std::endl; //Expected output: 5

    return 0;
}
```

I chose to replace `SomeType` with `int` to keep it simple, but assume relational operators (`<`,`<=`,`>`,`>=`) make no sense for this type.

So, I think I found a solution while asking the question, is there any better approach ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <unordered_map>

class Foo {
private:
    static int id_counter;
public:
    enum class Bar { _1, _2, _3, _4 };

    Bar bar;
    int id;

    Foo(Foo::Bar bar) : bar(bar), id(id_counter++) {}
};
int Foo::id_counter = 0;

struct EnumClassHash {
    template<typename T>
    std::size_t operator()(T t) const {
        return static_cast<std::size_t>(t);
    }
};

const Foo& findFoo(const std::vector<Foo>& vec) {
    std::unordered_map<Foo::Bar, int, EnumClassHash> priority;
    priority[Foo::Bar::_1] = 1;
    priority[Foo::Bar::_2] = 2;
    priority[Foo::Bar::_3] = 3;
    priority[Foo::Bar::_4] = 4;

    std::reference_wrapper<const Foo> bestFoo = vec.front();
    int bestPriority = priority[bestFoo.get().bar];

    for(const Foo& foo : vec) {
        if(priority[foo.bar] < bestPriority) {
            bestFoo = foo;
            bestPriority = priority[foo.bar];
        }
    }

    return bestFoo;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<Foo> fooVec1({Foo(Foo::Bar::_2),
                              Foo(Foo::Bar::_4),
                              Foo(Foo::Bar::_1),
                              Foo(Foo::Bar::_3)});

    std::vector<Foo> fooVec2({Foo(Foo::Bar::_3),
                              Foo(Foo::Bar::_2),
                              Foo(Foo::Bar::_4),
                              Foo(Foo::Bar::_2)});

    std::cout << findFoo(fooVec1).id << std::endl; //Expected output: 2
    std::cout << findFoo(fooVec2).id << std::endl; //Expected output: 5

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "is there any better approach ?" yes, just use `std::min_element` with custom comparator

Comment: Well, comparing elements doesn't make sense for the type I have to use in the real application. It's like trying to do `orange < banana`

Comment: What do you think you are doing here `if(priority[foo.bar] < bestPriority)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on Slava's comment:

```
const Foo& findFoo(const std::vector<Foo>& vec) {
    auto priority_less = [](const Foo & lhs, const Foo & rhs)
    {
        static std::unordered_map<Foo::Bar, int, EnumClassHash> priority {
            { Foo::Bar::_1, 1 },
            { Foo::Bar::_2, 2 },
            { Foo::Bar::_3, 3 },
            { Foo::Bar::_4, 4 },
        };

        return priority[lhs.bar] < priority[rhs.bar];
    };
    return *std::min_element(vec.begin(), vec.end(), priority_less);
}
```

Caveat: Your choice of `const Foo&` implies that `findFoo` is UB if `vec` is empty. I would return `std::vector<Foo>::const_iterator` instead, or `template <typename ForwardIterator> ForwardIterator findFoo(ForwardIterator, ForwardIterator)` to match other search algorithms